# Excel - test one cell string for values from column in another sheet and output the match?

Tags: excel-formula

Struggling to find an example or guidance that solves this issue.  Hoping someone has an answer.

In one sheet I have a list of transactions.  That sheet has a column, "Description", with a bunch of merged values (e.g., "My Name Is Rick").  In another sheet I have a large list of potential values (e.g., Rick, Julie, Jane, John, Sam, etc).

I need to search the cell for any match against the list of values, and I need the return to be the term that matched (e.g., Rick).

All of the solutions I'm finding tend to work the other way around... search an array for the value in a cell.

Appreciate any guidance or help.

Thanks,
Rick

Comment: Is the "list of values" all in one cell? Like Cell `A1` is `Rick,Morty,Lucy,Ethel` and you want to search `Pickle Rick is green` and have it return `Rick`? That's a tall order, if so and will probably require some VBA.

Comment: No.  There will only ever be one match for every cell searched.  The "transaction cells" I'm searching (the cells with the "my name is rick" type values) include about 600 total rows of cells.  I need to search those 600 cells to see if there is a term that matches from a separate list of 39000 values and, if it does, to return that match (e.g., Rick).  However, there will never be more than one term in the 39000 list that is found/matched in the cells I'm searching.

Comment: I found this, but for some reason I can't make it work... I get #N/A on the return.  https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-search-string-for-a-list-of-words

Comment: Got it. OK. Trying to think through this from an Array function standpoint.

Comment: This is the function I'm trying to use to do it, where there are two sheets; the sage data (txns) and the airpot reference.  L3 is a direct reference to a row to search in the sage data, and will increment when I paste the formula across multiple rows.  =INDEX('Airport Ref'!$A$2:$A$39145,LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Airport Ref'!$A$2:$A$39145,SageReportData1!$L3)),ROW(SageReportData1!$3:$656)),1))

Comment: That link is pretty good. Try `=INDEX(('Airport Ref'!$A$2:$A$39145, SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(('Airport Ref'!$A$2:$A$39145,SageReportData1!$L3))*ROW(('Airport Ref'!$A$2:$A$39145,)))`

Comment: The tricky bit is getting that `list` converted to a real range and making sense out of what they are doing with that `Row()` function inside the sumproduct. That should do the trick though given your ranges.

Comment: I get the message "you've entered too few arguments..." and it seems to highlight the area right at the end of the search function?  Also, I'm assuming this is an array... doesn't work regardless, but just wanted to check.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry. I accidently copied in the parantheses. `==INDEX('Airport Ref'!$A$2:$A$39145, SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Airport Ref'!$A$2:$A$39145,SageReportData1!$L3))*ROW('Airport Ref'!$A$2:$A$39145,)))`

Comment: Lol, that version says "too many arguments"?  I took out the extra =, but it still doesn't work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think I figured it out, extra , in the row function.  Seems to work great, thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Yep. Another stray comma. Those darned things. It seems like this will not work if your big list isn't unique, or if it has blanks in it, but other than those two caveats, this should do the trick.

Comment: Spoke too soon... It "functions" now, but none of the returns actually match the values in the fields I'm searching (the descriptions). I'm getting a combination of wrong data (e.g., Rick when Rick isn't in the actual string) and values that don't exist in either the string I'm searching or the list of names.  Sigh, so frustrating, I just don't really get how the Row component functions.  FYI, the "string list" is 600 rows (searching 1 cell in each row), the reference list is 39140-ish rows/values.

Comment: It's probably off by 1 because your search range doesn't start at 1. Do either of the following, but not both  1) Change to `=INDEX('Airport Ref'!$A$1:$A$39145` OR Change to `(ROW('Airport Ref'!$A$2:$A$39145)-1)`

Comment: Hmm... it's off more than that.  For example, the first row in my string data has LFMN, which is on 21167 on the Airport Ref table.  However, it's returning LIRS, which is 21568.  So it's off by 401, even after I added in the "-1".

Comment: I also tried it by modifying the airport ref table to start at row 1 (removed headers, updated formula), but does the same thing.  I can't figure out why the numbers are off... strange. Apologies, I can't start a chat or I'd share a screenshot.

Comment: Got it... I went to his source samples and was able to make it work.  AHHHHH!  Thanks for all the help, you rock!

Comment: That's great news!